# Groovy Script implementation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I would like to ask one question because I am not familiar with Groovy Script.

This command lists all the domains in my Cloudflare account. Basically I want to parameterize this by putting an "Active Choice Parameter" to Jenkins like a Groovy srcipt.

Can someone convert me this bash script to Groovy ?

```
curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?page=1&per_page=1000" -H "X-Auth-Email: e-mail" -H "X-Auth-Key: key" | 
  grep -Po '(?<="name":")[^"]*' | grep -v "string"
```

Thank you.

Comment: I tried to implemented like that but didn't work.

import groovy.json.*

println ["curl", "-X ", "GET", "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones?page=1&per_page=1000", "-H" , "X-Auth-Email:mail", "-H", "X-AuthKey:key"].execute().text
Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error?